# Extracting Numeric Values in R (from a Free text)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to extract the age(numeric values) from a vector , tryied the following but dint worked

Example:-

```
    a <- "age-32 agge32 age 45 aage 56 agee 34"
    b <- gsub("[Aa]g.e?"," age ",a)
    sa <- strsplit(x=b, split="\\s")
    age <- stringr::str_extract(sa, "(age?)(\\s[^\\s]+){1}")
     (or)
    age <- grep("(([^\\s]+\\s){0}(age)(\\s[^\\s]+){1})",sel,value = TRUE)
```

Comment: If you want to extract all numbers, try `str_extract_all(a,"\\d+")`.

Comment: Thanks for the earlier update , but Actually the Free text contains other digits like date, Address of a location , Pincode etc...I would like to extract the age(digits) which is followed by the character like "age|agge|age-|agee|Age" Example:- a <- "age-32 agge32 age 45 aage 56 agee 34 24-06-2015 DoorNo1,27/7, 3rd street, Wellington,pin 2100067"

Comment: sorry my mistake , The requirement is .I would like to extract only the age(digits) which is followed by the character like "age|agge|age-|agee|Age" 
 a <- "Father age-52 Mother agge42 Son age 9 Daugther aage 6 Address is door 23 20002, doc 26-07-1999 pincode 260074" > str_extract(str_extract_all(a,"(?>age|agg).+?\\d+")[[1]],"\\‌​‌​d+") 
Output:[1] NA NA NA NA 

Expected output is: 52 42 9 6 ..Need help on same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted:

```
library(stringr)

as.numeric(str_extract_all(a,"\\d+")[[1]])
```

OR using `gregexpr` and `regmatches` **BASE R**:

```
as.numeric(regmatches(a,gregexpr("\\d+",a))[[1]])
```

OR use `grep` and `strsplit` in **BASE R**:

```
as.numeric(grep("\\d+",strsplit(a,split=" |-|[a-zA-Z]")[[1]],value=T))
```

**Output**:

```
[1] 32 32 45 56 34
```

Comment: Thanks for the earlier update , but Actually the Free text contains other digits like date, Address of a location , Pincode etc...I would like to extract the age(digits) which is followed by the character like "age|agge|age-|agee|Age"

Example:-

  a <- "age-32 agge32 age 45 aage 56 agee 34  24-06-2015 DoorNo1,27/7, 3rd street, Wellington,pin 2100067"

Comment: @BalajiS  , A humble request, when you ask a question , put everything in it, how would I suppose to know that your data has date etc. You have never mentioned it there, Now this question is already voted for closed, Even someone wanted to help would not able to help you out. as per your solution , you can try this: `library(stringr); str_extract(str_extract_all(a,"(?>age|agg).\\d+")[[1]],"\\d+")`, This should work with the given string provided in your comment. also in case if this solution worked, please mark the answer as accepted using the green tick.

Comment: @BalajiS `library(stringr)` ; `str_extract(str_extract_all(a,"(?>age|agg).+?\\d+")[[1]],"\\d+")`, In case you have different spelling for age , add whatever version of age you wanted to put in the lookaround expression separated with pipe delimeter.

Comment: Thanks Kumar.. I tried as above but could not 

> a <- "Father age-52 Mother agge42 Son age 9 Daugther aage 6  Address is door 23 20002, doc 26-07-1999 pincode 260074"
> str_extract(str_extract_all(a,"(?>age|agg).+?\\d+")[[1]],"\\‌​d+")
Output:[1] NA NA NA NA

Expected output is:
  52 42 9 6
Need help on same

Comment: @BalajiS , Again you have changed your question but the above solution still holds , I am getting a solution with what i have pasted earlier, not sure what you are having as a text, `if you have copied pasted the earlier commands , do don't do it, type the entire thing and run it on the system`, It is working for me , It should be working for you. see the image of screenshot : https://ibb.co/mW702a

Comment: Yes Copy and paste dint worked(some 'dots' appear in between).
I typed it as u suggested and it works fine.. :)

Many Thanks Kumar.!!! :)